# Suddenly lots of bugs in my WP installation?

Tags: debug

I've been using WordPress for over 4 years without any issues.
But recently I get error messages from various sources (mostly plugins).
As all those plugins used to work just fine until a few days ago, I suppose it's not a problem within each plugin, but something happened to my WP core installation.

Just some examples of what I've noticed thus far:

**- Jetpack:**
cannot connect to WP anymore (32700 error):
*"Your Jetpack has a glitch. Something went wrong that’s never supposed to happen. Guess you’re just lucky: xml_rpc-32700
Try connecting again.
Error Details: The Jetpack server could not communicate with your site's XML-RPC URL. Please check to make sure http://zoomingjapan.com/xmlrpc.php is working properly. It should show 'XML‑RPC server accepts POST requests only.' on a line by itself when viewed in a browser and should not have any blank links or extra output anywhere."*

**- WordPress Editorial Calendar**
Error msg: *"An error occurred while loading the calendar:
The calendar was not able to parse the data your blog returned about the posts. This error is most likely caused by a conflict with another plugin on your blog. The actual parse error was:
JSON.parseIt"*

**- Appearance - Themes:**
When I try to "add new" themes I get the following error message:
*"An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with WordPress.org or this server’s configuration. If you continue to have problems, please try the support forums."*

Clearly there's something wrong with my WP installation.
I admit that I modified quite a few files in the past few days (e.g. htaccess, wp-config, funcion.php and some of my javascript files (my own, not the plugin ones).
I tried to undo my changes, but then my site broke, so it's impossible for me to figure out what's wrong.

PLEASE, can anybody help me figure out what to do?
There's possibly a lot more buggy things going on.
I NEED to fix this sooner or later.

I used "WP_Debug" to see if I can figure something out:

> Deprecated: Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated in /home/zoomingj/public_html/wp-content/themes/alltuts/functions.php on line 131

Notice: Constant EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS already defined in /home/zoomingj/public_html/wp-content/themes/alltuts/functions.php on line 25

Notice: register_sidebar was called incorrectly. No id was set in the arguments array for the "sidebar" sidebar. Defaulting to "sidebar-1". Manually set the id to "sidebar-1" to silence this notice and keep existing sidebar content. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 4.2.0.) in /home/zoomingj/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3599

Notice: register_sidebar was called incorrectly. No id was set in the arguments array for the "footer" sidebar. Defaulting to "sidebar-2". Manually set the id to "sidebar-2" to silence this notice and keep existing sidebar content. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 4.2.0.) in /home/zoomingj/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3599

Notice: Undefined index: wp-polls in /home/zoomingj/public_html/wp-includes/class.wp-scripts.php on line 222

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/zoomingj/public_html/wp-includes/class.wp-scripts.php on line 222

I can't find the mentioned problems, so here's the files:

/class.wp-scripts.php: http://pastebin.com/n5gSg0f1

/wp-includes/function.php: http://pastebin.com/cZtxwe2U

my theme's function.php: http://pastebin.com/beJkuQxZ

This is what I got. Just can't really work this out.
Most of these files I haven't touched in ages, so **I doubt they're causing my current issues**. All the plugins worked fine until a few days ago.

I'm trying to re-cap everything I did in the past few days.
I also installed **WP Optimize** and had it optimize my dabatase.
I tried a **CDN** for the first time (changing my nameservers for that). Didn't work out so well, so changed back to my hosts nameservers.
No idea if any of these could be related to my current problems.

**EDIT: PARTLY RESOLVED.**
I used a backup from April 2015 and replaced one file after another (the ones I modified in the past few days). After replacing the function.php in wp-includes everything works again.
I figured what I changed in that file. I wanted to force my own smilies and replaced / modified the original code with the following:

```
if ( !isset( $wpsmiliestrans ) ) {
    $wpsmiliestrans = array(
    ':mrgreen:' => 'mrgreen.png',
    ':neutral:' => "\xf0\x9f\x98\x90",
    ':twisted:' => "\xf0\x9f\x98\x88",
      ':arrow:' => "\xe2\x9e\xa1",
      ':smile:' => 'simple-smile.png',
        ':???:' => "\xf0\x9f\x98\x95",
       ':cool:' => "\xf0\x9f\x98\x8e",
       ':evil:' => "\xf0\x9f\x91\xbf",
       ':grin:' => "\xf0\x9f\x98\x80",
       ':idea:' => "\xf0\x9f\x92\xa1",
       ':oops:' => "\xf0\x9f\x98\xb3",
       ':razz:' => "\xf0\x9f\x98\x9b",
       ':roll:' => 'rolleyes.png',
       ':wink:' => "\xf0\x9f\x98\x89",
        ':cry:' => "\xf0\x9f\x98\xa5",
        ':eek:' => "\xf0\x9f\x98\xae",
        ':lol:' => "\xf0\x9f\x98\x86",
        ':mad:' => "\xf0\x9f\x98\xa1",
        ':sad:' => 'frownie.png',
          '8-)' => "\xf0\x9f\x98\x8e",
          '8-O' => "\xf0\x9f\x98\xaf",
          ':-(' => 'frownie.png',
          ':-)' => 'simple-smile.png',
          ':-?' => "\xf0\x9f\x98\x95",
          ':-D' => "\xf0\x9f\x98\x80",
          ':-P' => "\xf0\x9f\x98\x9b",
          ':-o' => "\xf0\x9f\x98\xae",
          ':-x' => "\xf0\x9f\x98\xa1",
          ':-|' => "\xf0\x9f\x98\x90",
          ';-)' => "\xf0\x9f\x98\x89",
    // This one transformation breaks regular text with frequency.
    //     '8)' => "\xf0\x9f\x98\x8e",
           '8O' => "\xf0\x9f\x98\xaf",
           ':(' => 'e%20(9).gif',
           ':)' => 'simple-smile.png',
           ':?' => "\xf0\x9f\x98\x95",
           ':D' => "e%20(17).gif",
           ':P' => "\xf0\x9f\x98\x9b",
           ':o' => "\xf0\x9f\x98\xae",
           ':x' => "\xf0\x9f\x98\xa1",
           ':|' => "\xf0\x9f\x98\x90",
           ';)' => "\xf0\x9f\x98\x89",
          ':!:' => "\xe2\x9d\x97",
          ':?:' => "\xe2\x9d\x93",
          ':reading:' => 'e%20(31).gif',
          'D:' => 'e%20(8).gif',
          ':mail:' => 'e(38).gif',
          ':luvit:' => 'e%20(5).gif',
          ':chu:' => 'e%20(33).gif',
          ':shock:' => 'e%20(25).gif',
          ':stressed:' => 'e%20(21).gif',
          ':sweatdrop:' => 'e%20(14).gif',
          ':rainy:' => 'e%20(37).gif',
          ':kyah:' => 'e%20(6).gif',
          ':stars:' => 'e%20(35).gif',
          ':present:' => 'e(39).gif',
          ':music:' => 'e%20(20).gif',
          ':sweatdrop2:' => 'e%20(26).gif',
          ';P' => 'e%20(15).gif',
          ':whyohwhy:' => 'e%20(1).gif',
          ':satisfied:' => 'e%20(22).gif',
          ':rabu:' => 'e%20(12).gif',
          ':fan:' => 'e%20(30).gif',
          ':peace:' => 'e(41).gif',
          ':notamused:' => 'e%20(19).gif',
          ':music2:' => 'e%20(2).gif',
          ':thumbup:' => 'e%20(29).gif',
          ':heart:' => 'e%20(11).gif',
          ':disappointed:' => 'e%20(36).gif',
          ':teary:' => 'e%20(10).gif',
          ':huh:' => 'e%20(32).gif',
          ':bah:' => 'e%20(13).gif',
          ':shiawase:' => 'e%20(16).gif',
          ':ehehe:' => 'e%20(28).gif',
          ':hum:' => 'e%20(24).gif',
          ':hearts:' => 'e%20(34).gif',
          ':hihi:' => 'e%20(23).gif',
          ':mukatsuku:' => 'e%20(18).gif',
          ':happy:' => 'e%20(4).gif',
          ':bleh:' => 'e%20(27).gif',
          ':ehno:' => 'e%20(7).gif',
          ':camera:' => 'e%20(3).gif',
          ':sparkling:' => 'e(40).gif',

    );
}
```

This is causing the problem. Do you have any idea why?

**I'd still love to get the debugging of above errors done, though.**
Thank you! ^_^

Thank you SO MUCH! :)

Comment: These debug notices are very explicit in telling you what the problem is and in most cases tells you what you need to do.

Comment: @PieterGoosen I can't seem to find the "register_sidebar" in line 3599 of the wp-includes function.php. This is most likely the culprit. How can I fix something that is not there? Even searching for the term "register_sidebar" doesn't help. It doesn't exist.

Comment: You should be changing core code or theme files if you haven't authored the theme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Has your hosting setup changed? The first three errors indicate that PHP can no longer make HTTP requests. [Check you have cURL enabled](http://www.mattsbits.co.uk/item-164.html).

> Deprecated: Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated in /home/zoomingj/public_html/wp-content/themes/alltuts/functions.php on line 131

If you weren't getting this error before, this indicates PHP has been upgraded - read up on how to fix the error. Essentially, remove the `&` reference from any function call parameters and make sure it's instead set for the parameter when *defining* the function:

```
// Change this...    
function do_something( $var ) {
    $var = 'something';
}

do_something( &$foo );


// To this...    
function do_something( &$var ) {
    $var = 'something';
}

do_something( $foo );
```

> Notice: Constant EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS already defined in /home/zoomingj/public_html/wp-content/themes/alltuts/functions.php on line 25

Remove the line from your `functions.php` and place it in your `wp-config.php`:

```
define( 'EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS', X );
```

> Notice: register_sidebar was called incorrectly.

Just make sure you set the `id` in your args:

```
register_sidebar(
    array(
         'id' => 'sidebar-1',
         // other args
    )
);

register_sidebar(
    array(
         'id' => 'sidebar-2',
         // other args
    )
);
```

The WP Polls error, well, that's for the plugin author. For now, once you've fixed everything in your theme, switch debugging off for your live site in `wp-config.php`:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );
```

Comment: I don't exactly understand how / where to toss and add the "&" in my function.php without breaking anything. Could you have a look at my function.php (line 131) and past a code for that here? Also, I cannot find the "register_sidebar" AT ALL in the function.php of wp-includes. Where is it?

Comment: Line 131, change `parent::end_el( &$output` to `parent::end_el( $output`

Comment: Line 508, in `functions.php`, those are your `register_sidebar` calls.

Comment: Thank you.
I still don't get how / why I should make two sidebars out of one in the code. What exactly do I replace with what?

Comment: Just add the `id` argument to each call - it's in my answer.

Comment: I think I got it.

Comment: I guess somewhere you're calling `dynamic_sidebar( 1 )` and `dynamic_sidebar( 2 )`? These map to your `sidebar-X` widget areas. Just add the `id` as described, WordPress is doing it anyway but just complaining that you're not setting them yourself.

Comment: I got it. Thanks. Concerning the wp-poll error. I might have caused that as I deregistered the CSS and Javascript to call it just where I need it.